# Modifying master page created using design manager in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage, design-manager

Someone has created Master page using design manager. Now I want to modify this master page to make some changes.

Which is the best way to do it without breaking the original master page?

Comment: use SharePoint Designer to modify it

Answer (score 0):

Copy your existing masterpage html file to same directory with another name. New masterpage automatically will be created. Change site master page to new one and modify its html, as you want. Masterpages stored in /_catalogs/masterpage folder of your site.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to continue the development further on the master page, I would suggest export the design package and import and apply in a developer site.

Before Changes

> Production -> Export Package -> Developer Site -> Import Package ->
>   Make Changes

Customize the new developer site and export and import the package from the developer site to the production package.

After changes

> Developer Site -> Export Package -> Production Site -> Import Package

This will give you a site to test and continue working for any future changes.

Thanks and hope this helps
Deepak